# How to handle large data in DotNet console app build on VS2017?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, memory

I'm building the DotNet console application in Visual Studio-2017 which would create some reports. In order to produce the report, application program will read large amount of data from ORACLE DB and process. Data size is up to 4GB. Application will be hosted on Windows 2016 server, 64 bit process and 8GB RAM size.

But I'm getting out-of-memory exception. I did change Project->Properties->Build->Platform Target->X64 bit but no use. I read some articles that by adding `editbin /largeaddressaware "$(TargetPath)"` in post build tab will help. Is it true? If so, what would be the value for "TargetPath"? How much maximum memory that one application process could allocate for above system configuration?

Comment: Can you read data by paging?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you want to handle large data in DotNet console app build on VS2017.

It is available to add editbin /largeaddressaware "$(TargetPath)" in the post build tab.

But you will not find editbin. Therefore, the location of editbin.exe must be determined 
locally.
E.g:
[image]

"C:\Program Files (x86)\VS2019pro\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\vc15\VC\bin\editbin.exe" /largeaddressaware "$(TargetPath)"

$(TargetPath) represents the absolute path of the main output file generated by the project.

Check if large memory application is supported
Run cmd, cd to the directory of editbin.exe, enter the following command to view the properties of the exe
dumpbin /headers c:/****/*.exe
(Note that it needs to be a full path).

After entering, a prompt will appear as shown in the attachment indicating that the success.The picture shows that the application memory is greater than 2GB.